# How to merge two roles into one, and delete the two old ones?

Tags: powershell-extensions, role-management

We have an old Sitecore installation, and I need to clean up and consolidate our own created roles. We have partial overlapping roles and too many to make them useful. I prefer to do it with spe or C# and not directly in the db.

So to be more precise - how do I extract the rights to the items from each of the two roles and merge the two into one new role and delete the two old one’s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPE includes a toolbox item called "Transfer item security" which provides a way to query what's in the database matching a role or user and transfer ownership to a new role.

You can find the source code here if you are on a version of SPE prior to 6.4.

https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/5c672b42b3a1859e36c82f426a10e053c8001608/unicorn/SPE/Scripts/SPE/SPE/Tools/Security%20Management/Toolbox/Security%20Management/Transfer%20item%20security.yml

https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/975

Comment: Just what I was looking for Thx Michael!!!!!